# Add text on image that was loaded by javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<li>
    <a href="../images/fullsize/Agave.jpg" class="zoom" title="image1" onclick=""><img src="../images/thumbs/Agave.jpg" alt="" /></a>
</li>
```

i have JavaScript that will expand image but i have one more task,i need to add text on expanded image (Agave.jpg) it is possible?

Comment: 1. simple inline html node with text above; 2. load image to a canvas and then draw on it

Answer (score 0):

You can use the image as a background of the anchor element:

```
<a href="../images/fullsize/Agave.jpg" class="zoom" title="image1" onclick="" style="background: url(../images/thumbs/Agave.jpg) no-repeat 0 0;width:[img-width]px;height:[img-height]px">
Agave.jpg
</a>
```

Note that only the text within the anchor will act like a link.